# nVidia RTX 2080 driver issue with remote desktop (VNC, NX, etc.)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, vnc, nx

Description: The screen (especially terminal programs such as Terminal and Terminator) do not refresh properly when using any kind of remote desktop. There is occasionally quite a long lag, for example, when typing into a terminal window. If I switch to nouveau driver the issue goes away completely. The issue appears with both nVidia 430 and 440 versions. Old drivers don't support RTX 20 cards so I can't for example try 390.

I tried different remote desktop servers such as the NX NoMachine, and VNC vine, as well as different clients on MacOS and Windows, I even tried TeamViewer, all behave the same.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and no change.

Both the server and client are connected to wired gigabit router.

Comment: Seems I'm not the only person with this issue: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1045056/linux/vnc-server-on-nvidia-linux-does-not-refresh-screen-after-every-keystroke/?offset=10#5426708

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is there since like two years. Not addressed by nVidia.

I see it with Ubuntu 18.04 and GeForce GTX 750 Ti, using X11VNC to connect.

Enabling seconds in GNOME clock makes the screen refresh at least once a second, which helps if you need a fast workaround:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```